# How to automate oAuth2.0 authorization in Python?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, postman

I'm using oAuth2.0 Authorization with grant type as 'Client Credentials' in Postman to get the new access token. Once the token is generated, I hit the API URL in the POST method and get JSON response for a payload.

I have below details -
a. Access Token URL
b. API URL
c. Client ID
d. Client Secret code

I want to automate this process in Python.

The research I did so far asks for authorize_url/redirect_uri/base_url however I don't have these details (unless there is a gap in my understanding)

Could someone please help me here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggets the [Authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/) package in Python. It has built in classes handling the OAuth1/Oauth2 flows. You can create your client with the necessary credentials (`client_id`, `client_secret`, etc.). You can also check [this](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) for some python examples.